How does nginx achieve zero TIME_WAIT sockets under load testing on Windows?
While implementing a C++ HTTP server on Windows, I'm investigating how nginx handles socket cleanup. Using netstat, I observe that after handling multiple concurrent requests with hey benchmarking tool, nginx maintains zero sockets in TIME_WAIT state.
My understanding of TCP socket states:

TIME_WAIT occurs on the connection-terminating endpoint
When server initiates close, its socket enters TIME_WAIT
When client initiates close, client socket enters TIME_WAIT
TIME_WAIT typically lasts 2MSL (Maximum Segment Lifetime)

My current implementation:

Standard Windows socket API (Winsock2) with I/O CP
Proper socket cleanup with closesocket()
SO_REUSEADDR enabled
Basic HTTP request handling

Despite these measures, my server accumulates sockets in TIME_WAIT when closing connections. However, nginx somehow avoids this entirely.
What techniques or socket configurations does nginx employ to achieve zero TIME_WAIT sockets? Are there specific Windows-related optimizations in play?
I've already investigated:

Connection keepalive settings
SO_LINGER socket options
TCP_NODELAY
Various client-initiated close strategies


nginx is open-source, so why not simply look through its source code to see what it actually does?

Because I don't know which of the many functions Nginx performs is responsible for this behavior, and someone here might know exactly what it is.

Nginx achieves zero TIME_WAIT sockets under load testing on Windows by leveraging connection reuse and the "reuseport" feature, which enables multiple worker processes to bind to the same port, distributing load efficiently. Additionally, Nginx uses non-blocking I/O, optimized connection handling, and proper timeout settings to minimize socket exhaustion. By avoiding unnecessary closures and keeping connections alive with keep-alive mechanisms, it reduces the accumulation of TIME_WAIT states under heavy load.

This feels like an AI generated answer, which is not allowed on this site. And Windows doesn't support a "reuseport" socket option.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
